# Does $\int_{0}^1 i\times I\{x_i<\nu\} di$ exist?

Tags: integration, probability-theory

$$
\int_{0}^1 i\times I\{x_i<\nu\} di
$$
where $x_i$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ and iid across $i$. Parameter $\nu\in(0,1)$.

By law of large numbers, we know $\int_{0}^1 I\{x_i<\nu\} di=\nu$ because $x_i$ is iid. But $i\times I\{x_i<\nu\}$ is no longer iid.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote here doesn't make sense: a continuum of independent continuously distributed random variables on a fixed probability space doesn't really exist in any useful sense; in particular, it can't have Riemann integrable or even Lebesgue measurable sample paths.

What does make sense however is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} I(X_k<\nu) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k I(X_k<\nu)$$

where $X_k$ is a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables uniform on $[0,1]$. This is basically the "naive conversion" of the expression you wrote into the notation of Riemann sums with uniform partitions.

One way to look at this is through the lens of convergence in probability: the summands have mean $k\nu$ and variance $k^2 \nu(1-\nu)$ so the whole thing has mean $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k}{n^2} \nu \to \nu/2$ and variance $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \nu(1-\nu)}{n^4} \to 0$, so it converges in probability to the constant $\nu/2$ by Chebyshev's inequality.

Note that $\nu/2=\nu \int_0^1 x dx$, and this is the typical situation for "reasonable" functions: you'll get $\nu$ (the probability that any one summand "counts") times the corresponding deterministic integral.

I am less confident offhand how to deduce a.s. convergence; if I had to venture a guess I would try the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: Thanks, Ian! A quick question is, if the integration is over $[0,\lambda]$ for some real number $\lambda$, how should we set up the corresponding discrete approximation?

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu Replace $\frac{k}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ in the left side of my inline equation by $\frac{k\lambda}{n}$ and $\frac{\lambda}{n}$ respectively and then continue from there.

Comment: I see. So we are just dividing any real interval into small $1/n$ sub-intervals. Thank you!